# How to get specific datatype property using SPARQL in Protege

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

This is my ontology:

[image: Class views]

I have an individual and I set two different datatype properties: "code" and "EnglishName". In SPARQL, I can get all datatype properties of individual:

[image: SPARQL results]

Query:

```
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE { uni:舌苔厚度厚 ?x ?y. ?x a owl:DatatypeProperty}
```

The question:

1. Why every datatype property appears twice in the result?
2. If I want to get value of one datatype property (not of all datatype properties), what do I suppose to do?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You get two results because there are two object property assertions with the property and two different values. And for each possible match, you'll get a separate row. 2. append `LIMIT 1` to the query if you want only one row back

Comment: Just as a comment, please try to improve the English of your question. Some phrases are confusing.

Comment: I'm so sorry that my English is poor. I will improve it.Thank you for your help. But in the question 2 if I only want to get one of the specific datatypeproperty like "code" or "EnglishName"  what do i suppose to do?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify this in the query, i.e. instead of `?x` you write the URI of the property and you can omit the last triple pattern indeed: `SELECT ?y WHERE { uni:舌苔厚度厚 <THE_URI_OF_THE_PROPERTY> ?y . }` or if you still need the property `SELECT ?y WHERE { uni:舌苔厚度厚 ?x ?y . FILTER(?x = <THE_URI_OF_THE_PROPERTY>) }`

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for your response.But I try as you said :`SELECT ?y WHERE { uni:舌苔厚度厚 uni:code ?y . } ` or `SELECT ?y WHERE { uni:舌苔厚度厚 ?x ?y . FILTER(?x = uni:code) }`  both it no results return.What mistake did i make? Thank you.

Comment: If your original query does work and returns two rows with at least one row for the property `uni:code` then it should work with both queries. But I don't know your ontology and I don't know if `uni` is the correct prefix for the property or whether you have a different one used. You should try to use the full URI instead of the prefixed one.

Comment: @AKSW  Thank you for your help. But the full URI what it's that mean? 
`uni` is the correct prefix in my ontology and I have an individual  `舌苔厚度厚 ` .I set two `Data property`  "code" and "EnglishName" each one have own value. see [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ4rB.jpg
But it doesn't work. Where i missed it?

Comment: The full URI is a full URI...: `<http://example.org/A>` is a full URI. The image doesn't help here, please upload the ontology to some public place e.g. Gist

Comment: @AKSW OK.I will create a new ontology and upload. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AKSW I find something different. When I create a new Objectproperty in my  [ontology](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/90ecf686d2a168539a73d4a2bedb6bfb)
The Declaration show `<ObjectProperty abbreviatedIRI="ont:hasObject"/>`.But I saw on [OWL2 WebOntology Sample](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c59627046d11afb0ee0b5c2a85af6c7).There create Class one Declaration show `<Class IRI="#Animal"/>` and another show `<Class abbreviatedIRI="myOnt:Tabloid"/>`. What is different  `abbreviatedIRI` and  `IRI`? If I only want to create `<Class IRI="#Animal"/>`.what should i suppose to do? Thanks